# Filtering a list as you type with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I was planning to create an unordered list of users of my web application using a simple database query, but then was planning to let people filter this list down by typing the person's name they're looking for into a text input.

I was hoping to use jQuery to match the string in the input box to any inside one of the list items, then hide the other ones, maybe by applying a new class dynamically to the ones that contain the matching string, and hiding all others that don't contain that class.

Does anyone know of a good way to do this?

Comment: You should check out AngularJS which can do that easily with almost no code, when you need something like this multiple times in one project :)

Comment: I use angular almost exclusively now, this was posted six years ago. Wow...now i feel old.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Assuming that your `ul` has an `id` of `theList`, the following would be one way of doing it.

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="filter(this)" />

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function filter(element) {
        var value = $(element).val();

        $("#theList > li").each(function() {
            if ($(this).text().search(value) > -1) {
                $(this).show();
            }
            else {
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

If you don't wish to have case-sensitive filter then add `.toLowerCase()` to these lines like so:

```
var value = $(element).val().toLowerCase();
if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().search(value) > -1)
```

Alternatively for a more concise version based on what Marek Tihkan posted you could replace the each() loop with the following. Not sure whether this would perform better or worse.

```
$('#theList > li:not(:contains(' + value + '))').hide(); 
$('#theList > li:contains(' + value + ')').show();
```

Comment: <li> hide() and show() working but not comparing with input value

Comment: This code run on the static content if i have php while loop then its not working

Comment: Phouf! Easiest javascript implementation I've ever completed. Thank you.

Comment: The method with "each" is easier to adapt to ignore uppercases and accented chars.

Comment: Your own method works better when there is no need to have filter case sensitive. It should be something like: `var value = $(element).val().toLowerCase();` and `$(this).text().toLowerCase().search(value) > -1`

Answer (score 12):

The solution given by Nikolas combined with the one of Marek rise an error if the input text is empty. 
The solution below corrects that and works for lists surrounded by an 'a' tag.
 
The function is also designed to filter elements with words having their first letter uppercased (as for example with names). The filtering is thus ordered. If you type 'An' or 'an' then you will get all the elements in the list starting by those letters (e.g. Anthony will match but Fanny no).

```
function filter (element,what) {
    var value = $(element).val();
    value = value.toLowerCase().replace(/\b[a-z]/g, function(letter) {
        return letter.toUpperCase();
    });

    if (value == '') {
        $(what+' > a > li').show();
    }
    else {
        $(what + ' > a > li:not(:contains(' + value + '))').hide();
        $(what + ' > a > li:contains(' + value + ')').show();
    }
};
```

Below is a sample HTML code that works with the script:

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="filter(this,'theList')" />
<ul id="theList">
    <li><a href="">Tyrone Schlecht</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Javier Ress</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Carlene Tomes</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Neil Aigner</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Nita Schreffler</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Clinton Knuckles</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Eve Kellett</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Jamie Kaspar</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Emilia Hooton</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Kenya Sidney</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It is not valid HTML to have an anchor (a) tag as a child of UL.

Comment: You may want to update your jQuery code to match your HTML edit.

Answer (score 8):

I did it by iterating all of them and hide those witch didn't match and showed those which matched.

```
$('li').hide(); 
$('li:contains(' + needle + ')').show();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [LiveQuery](http://ejohn.org/blog/jquery-livesearch/) which was ported from php to jQuery by John Resig.

*Note*:  It has a dependency on [Quicksilver's `score` method in PHP](https://gist.github.com/kenzie/383465) method, which has been ported to JavaScript by [`LiquidMetal.score`](https://github.com/rmm5t/liquidmetal) and [joshaven's `string.score`](https://github.com/joshaven/string_score)

**Usage Example**:

```
$("#text_box_selector").liveUpdate("#list_selector");
```

*Note*: `#list_selector` must find an element that contains `li` elements

#### Plugin + Sort + Live Demo

```js
// https://github.com/joshaven/string_score
String.prototype.score = function (word, fuzziness) {
  'use strict';

  // If the string is equal to the word, perfect match.
  if (this === word) { return 1; }

  //if it's not a perfect match and is empty return 0
  if (word === "") { return 0; }

  var runningScore = 0,
      charScore,
      finalScore,
      string = this,
      lString = string.toLowerCase(),
      strLength = string.length,
      lWord = word.toLowerCase(),
      wordLength = word.length,
      idxOf,
      startAt = 0,
      fuzzies = 1,
      fuzzyFactor,
      i;

  // Cache fuzzyFactor for speed increase
  if (fuzziness) { fuzzyFactor = 1 - fuzziness; }

  // Walk through word and add up scores.
  // Code duplication occurs to prevent checking fuzziness inside for loop
  if (fuzziness) {
    for (i = 0; i < wordLength; i+=1) {

      // Find next first case-insensitive match of a character.
      idxOf = lString.indexOf(lWord[i], startAt);

      if (idxOf === -1) {
        fuzzies += fuzzyFactor;
      } else {
        if (startAt === idxOf) {
          // Consecutive letter & start-of-string Bonus
          charScore = 0.7;
        } else {
          charScore = 0.1;

          // Acronym Bonus
          // Weighing Logic: Typing the first character of an acronym is as if you
          // preceded it with two perfect character matches.
          if (string[idxOf - 1] === ' ') { charScore += 0.8; }
        }

        // Same case bonus.
        if (string[idxOf] === word[i]) { charScore += 0.1; }

        // Update scores and startAt position for next round of indexOf
        runningScore += charScore;
        startAt = idxOf + 1;
      }
    }
  } else {
    for (i = 0; i < wordLength; i+=1) {
      idxOf = lString.indexOf(lWord[i], startAt);
      if (-1 === idxOf) { return 0; }

      if (startAt === idxOf) {
        charScore = 0.7;
      } else {
        charScore = 0.1;
        if (string[idxOf - 1] === ' ') { charScore += 0.8; }
      }
      if (string[idxOf] === word[i]) { charScore += 0.1; }
      runningScore += charScore;
      startAt = idxOf + 1;
    }
  }

  // Reduce penalty for longer strings.
  finalScore = 0.5 * (runningScore / strLength    + runningScore / wordLength) / fuzzies;

  if ((lWord[0] === lString[0]) && (finalScore < 0.85)) {
    finalScore += 0.15;
  }

  return finalScore;
};

// http://ejohn.org/apps/livesearch/jquery.livesearch.js
jQuery.fn.liveUpdate = function(list) {
  list = jQuery(list);

  if (list.length) {
    var rows = list.children('li'),
      cache = rows.map(function() {
        return this.innerHTML.toLowerCase();
      });

    this
      .keyup(filter).keyup()
      .parents('form').submit(function() {
        return false;
      });
  }

  return this;

  function filter() {
    var term = jQuery.trim(jQuery(this).val().toLowerCase()),
      scores = [];

    if (!term) {
      rows.show();
    } else {
      rows.hide();

      cache.each(function(i) {
        var score = this.score(term);
        if (score > 0) {
          scores.push([score, i]);
        }
      });

      jQuery.each(scores.sort(function(a, b) {
        return b[0] - a[0];
      }), function() {
        jQuery(rows[this[1]]).show();
      });
    }
  }
};

$("#search").liveUpdate("#colors");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="search"><br/>

<ul id="colors">
  <li>Cat Book</li>
  <li>Dog Basket</li>
  <li>Bear Cub</li>
  <li>Car Door</li>
  <li>Another option</li>
  <li>Another Animal</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Just a shorter version
$('ul>li').hide().has(':contains(' + needle + ')').show();

// case insensitive searching with animation
$("ul>li").slideUp().filter( function() {
     return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(needle) > -1
}).stop(true).fadeIn();
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking main inspiration from [this W3 example](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_filters.asp), I developed a possible alternative and [compact solution](https://jsfiddle.net/ldetomi/k75xL6sb/52/).

In the example linked is possible to see 3 different options:

- Filter only UL items
- Filter any item
- Filter any item with css animated effect

The simplest JS code is the following, that simply filter any kind of element thanks to `$("#anyItemList *")` selector:

```
  $("#anyItemListInputFilter").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#anyItemList *").filter(function() {
        let item = $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1;
      $(this).toggle(item);
    });
  });
```

In case that desired filtering would be only for `UL` list, that selector could changed with `$("#ulList li")` (as in example)

If you want also to add css animation effect, there are some constraints:

- Needed a pre-defined `max-height` in `px` (maybe not so much impacting if you set an enough taller one)
- `overflow-y:hidden;`

So I was forced to declare:

```
#anyItemAnimatedList * {
  transition:all 0.5s ease;
  opacity:1;
  max-height:500px;
 overflow-y:hidden;
}

#anyItemAnimatedList ul {
  list-style-position:inside;
}

#anyItemAnimatedList .hidden {
  max-height:0;
  opacity:0;
  border:0;
}
```

Hiding effect is made with a combination of `opacity` and `max-height` css transitions, and `border:0` is necessary to override `button` tag default browser style.

In addition, in case of `OL` and `UL` lists is necessary to set `list-style-position:inside;` due to a strange default behaviour shared by Firefox and Chrome that hide bullets in case of default `list-style-position:outside`.

For Firefox this is a [known bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=187267) since 2003!!! but also Chrome [has the same behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843495/css-overflowhidden-hiding-a-lists-bullets#answer-4843567).

Answer (score 0):

```js
var text = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
                
$("li").each(function() {
    $(this).text().toLowerCase().search(text) > -1 ? $(this).show() : $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.