# CSS overflow:hidden hiding a list's bullets?

Tags: html, css, overflow, html-lists

I've just noticed something funny. Let's say I have a HTML list:

```
<ol>
    <li>Lorem</li>
    <li>ipsum</li>
    <li>dolor</li>
    <li>sit amet enim. Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis. Maecenas malesuada elit lectus felis, malesuada ultricies. Curabitur et ligula.</li>
</ol>
```

And this CSS:

```
li {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

The long text in the last item is indeed hacked off when it goes off the container's width, as expected. BUT! The list item numbers are affected by the `overflow` property too and are not shown.

However, modifying the CSS like this:

```
ol {
    overflow: hidden;
}
li {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

works as intended (text won't go out of the container, but list items are shown). At least all this is true for Firefox 4 beta10.

Don't you think that the numbering being affected by the `overflow` is a bit illogical? Why would that happen? Is it intende behaviour? Is it in the specification or is it just some oddity someone forgot to deal with?

Comment: is this all 4 beta10 behaviour? Or did you tested on other browsers as well?

Comment: No, I didn't test because I don't really care about fixing this (setting `overflow` on the `ol` does the trick, I'm just curious)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This is the default behavior as far as I´m aware, if the `list-style-position` is `outside`, bullets of an `ul` and numbers of an `ol` do not show. At least in Firefox, I remember seeing it before in older versions.

Comment: Aha! Good one! I just checked it and indeed, `list-style-position:inside` makes the bullets appear inside the `li`, and they are not affected by the `overflow` anymore. I suspected something similar, but wasn't sure. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Browsers add default margin and padding to lists. Try using a reset.css first to remove default styles that way you can start clean and fresh without unexpected behavior. Do a search for Eric Meyer's reset. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen my bullets/numbers get clipped when there is not enough padding on the left side of the ul. Try adding a bit and see if that helps.

Comment: Not really. In my particular case, there's 40px of padding. The bullets are entirely inside the `ol`'s padding. I think it has more to do with some strange behaviour of `li` elements (I think their bullets are rendered outside the actual `li`)... Have I just answered my question?

Comment: Sort of. Check out list-style-position

Answer (score -2):

The way, I solved the problem.
I just wrapped content of 'li' to 'div' tag.
And added style 'overflow: hidden' to it

Comment: A `div` is not a valid child of a list tag, be it an `ol`, `ul` or `dl`.