# Ellipsis on an anchor inside a list element hides list bullet points

Tags: html, css

I have a list with disc bullet points, and when I apply an ellipsis on the text inside the element, it hides the bullet point.

After discovering that if I apply `overflow: hidden` on the list itself, it will hide the bullet point. So I moved this rule onto the anchor within the list element, but it still hides the parent list element's disc for some reason. However, if i add a sibling element to the anchor, it works..

Example seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/EByrk/1/

Answer (score 3):

Applying `list-style-position:inside` to the List works by keeping it inside the overflow.

However, I'm still confused by the behavior described in the question. Is this a bug?

Comment: Seems to be your only option. Same solution was settled on here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843495/css-overflowhidden-hiding-a-lists-bullets

Comment: Or you could use `:before` etc. as an alternative. See answer below.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to positioning the bullets `inside`, you could use an artifice like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
ul {padding-left: 10px;}
li {width: 150px; position: relative;}
li a { 
    display: block;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

li:before {
    content:"\2022 ";
    padding:0 5px 0 0;
    vertical-align:middle;
    position: absolute;
    left: -15px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
    <li><a href="#">This is a long line of text lorem ipsum dolor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">This is shorter</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">This is a long line of text lorem ipsum dolor</a></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the `display` property of `li a` to `inline-block` will preserve the bullets.

```
li a { 
  display: inline-block;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```