# How to filter data from dynamically generated list?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

Currently I am working on one web application in asp.net.
Application received data from web-service in json format. Requirement is to develop controls dynamically, I did it using html controls. I dynamically created list of label & stored values in it. Now I want to add filter on the top of that list so that it can filter data based on vales entered in the textbox.
I want something like below textbox list of data like item1, item2 and so on, based on value entered in textbox. I need to filter data.
How I can achieve this?I tried to use list.js but it didn't work.

```
<% foreach (var item in (List<string>)Session["list"])
  { 
%>
<%--<li><label onclick="redirect('<%:item %>')"><%: item %></label><br/></li>--%>       
   <li><%:item %></li>
<% } %>
```

Comment: <% foreach (var item in (List<string>)Session["list"]){%>
<%--<li><label onclick="redirect('<%:item %>')"><%: item %></label><br /></li>--%>
<li><%:item %></li>
   <%} %>

Answer (score 0):

Add texbox with onkeyup event handler, set some id to ul e.g. id="list"

```
  <input type="text" onkeyup="filter(this)" />
  <ul id="list">
      <li>a</li>
      <li>abc</li>
      <li>bcd</li>
      <li>abc</li>
  </ul>
```

Add the following script ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1772035/filtering-a-list-as-you-type-with-jquery)) and a reference to jquery

```
  <script>
    function filter(element) {
        var value = $(element).val(); 
        $("#list > li").each(function() {
            if ($(this).text().search(value) > -1) {
                $(this).show();
            }
            else {
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });
    }
  </script>
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/hahodetu/1/edit?html,output