# How to implement search filter in asp.net mvc?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a homepage, and I want to add a searchbox to filter my following code, and display the only information according to the provided location from searchbox. How can I achieve the search filter by using javascript?

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchText" placeholder="Search by location.."/>

    @foreach (var scr in Model)
    {
        <li>
            <div class="date">
                <div class="month">
                    @scr.DateTime.ToString("MMM")
                </div>
                <div class="day">
                    @scr.DateTime.ToString("d ")
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="details1">
                <div><strong>@scr.TeamA vs @scr.TeamB</strong><small> (@scr.Competition.Name) </small>
                </div>
                <div>@scr.Organizer.Organizer</div>
                <div><small>@scr.Organizer.Street, @scr.Organizer.City</small>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="details2">
                <input class="btn btn-info" type="button" value="Details" onclick="location.href = '@Url.Action("Details", "Screenings")?id=' + @scr.Id"/>
            </div>
        </li>
    }
```

Comment: Take a look here, it has the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1772084/4868839

Comment: look at this plug in. It might help you https://datatables.net/