# How to filter by search a list that is populated through ajax?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a script that gets JSON data and uses it to create a list of Title+Image. All items are shown on load.

I want to create a search box so that as you type, it will only show you the matching ones.

As the Ajax gets the JSON, it already surrounds the details in the proper tags. So I tried to put < li> tags around them, so that I can use some tutorials on
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_lists.asp. But this only shrunk and squish the list. And it didnt search

This is the part that retrieves:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url://gets from here,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: "json",
    success: listThemAll
  });
});
```

and then it does the listThemAll function which takes the json and puts them into a array:

```
function listThemAll(info){
  var titleName = [];
  var picLink = [];
  //some more vars
  $.each(info, function(index, value){
    picLink.push(value.imageLink);
    titleName.push(value.nameTitle);
   //some more pushed
  });
  //length (total entries) determined
```

then for each item in the length, it wraps the stuff with the HTML tags.

```
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    var image = '<div class="... > + pickLink[i] + ... </div>'; //here is where I tried to add <li></li> tags
```

and it does that for the titles as well.

So my question is, is is possible to filter these by a search bar using just the HTML and Javascript? How do I amend it like that? So if I search "Knight" it should show the results that start with "Knight"

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicated, see if this help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1772035/filtering-a-list-as-you-type-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. In your input element you need an event handler for on `onchange` event (or `onkeydown`). When a user types something, you should get a `value` of your search input and filter your list of options against your input value.

And yes, as it is said in the comment, a lot of people have already solved the same task many times before, feel free to look at their code.

Comment: But the link in the comment has people filtering < ul> and < li> tags. I do not have them and have tried to put them, but it does not work the same way